# How to show a screen can be scrolled down?

Tags: scrolling, touch-screen, swipe, discovery

Back in the old days scroll bars were used to show if and how much a page can be scrolled down. I'm working on a smartphone app and the settings screen takes up more than one screen and needs to be scrolled. The trouble is, from the top it looks like it could be all there is and the user is given no indication they can scroll down for more settings. Scrolling is done, in the normal smartphone way, where a finger can drag to move the container.

Comment: Could you add the screenshot of the Settings screen for better judgement of why you are facing the problem? Also which platform is this app being developed for?